# Fade transition for Carousel in Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to modify the new Bootstrap 4 Beta Carousel to transition from slide to slide with fade rather than a sliding action, and using CSS. I cannot get it to work. I'm not sure if a special Javascript call is required.

Please see Codepen here:

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://tuniverse.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/boss-tu-2-06.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://tuniverse.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/boss-tu-2-08.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://tuniverse.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/boss-tu-2-09.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end carousel -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, thanks I've repeatedly tried to get that piece of code to work with no luck. But thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: The link I posted has **working** code. You don't need to try and get it working if it's working...

Comment: Tell you what -- have a look at the code I posted and help me out.

Comment: It looks like the Bootstrap team made changes to the Carousel component in the 4 Beta release. This explains why the code you referenced above as working doesn't work (for me), that is, since I'm using the beta version of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with Bootstrap 4 Beta.

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
.carousel-inner {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-item {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5; /*Added clone in this line*/
}
a.carousel-control-next:link, a.carousel-control-prev:link {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .5;
}
a.carousel-control-next:hover, a.carousel-control-prev:hover  {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  position:relative;
  background-image: none;
}    
.carousel-control-next-icon:before {
  top:0;
  left:-5px;
  padding-right:10px;
 }
.carousel-control-prev-icon:before {
  top:0;
  left:-5px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/FmtTabr.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div> <!-- close carousel-item 1 -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="position: absolute; top:0px; width: 100% ; height: 100%">
     <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/UioJ4ix.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div> <!-- close carousel-item 2 -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="position: absolute; top:0px; width: 100% ; height: 100%">
     <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/UkPZYcB.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div> <!-- close carousel-item 3 -->
   </div> <!-- close carousel-inner -->

   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div> <!-- close carousel -->

  <table class="table table-bordered mt-3">
   <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
     <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Table head</th> 
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>content</td>
     <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>content</td>
     <td>content</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
    </div> <!-- end col-lg-8 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 sidebar">
     <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div> <!-- close sidebar -->
  </div>  <!-- close row -->
</div> <!-- close container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I just want this effect, but I have conflicts with display:block, do you know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works with **Bootstrap 4 Stable Released**

Starting from this theme: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

```css
#image1 {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1440x813');
}

#image2 {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1440x813');
}

#image3 {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1440x813');
}

.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-image: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.carousel.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel.fade .carousel-item {
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    left: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel.fade .carousel-item:first-child {
    top: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel.fade .carousel-item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
 z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">

 <title>Full Slider - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

 <!-- Navigation -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
       <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel fade" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div id="image1" class="carousel-item active">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h3>First Slide</h3>
      <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
     </div>
    </div><!-- #image1 -->
    <div id="image2" class="carousel-item">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h3>Second Slide</h3>
      <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
     </div>
    </div><!-- #image2 -->
    <div id="image3" class="carousel-item">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h3>Third Slide</h3>
      <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
     </div>
    </div><!-- #image3 -->
   </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div><!-- carouselExampleIndicators -->
 </header>

 <!-- Page Content -->
 <section class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Full Slider by Start Bootstrap</h1>
   <p>The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The rest of the styles for this template are contained within the
    <code>full-slider.css</code> file.
   </p>
  </div>
 </section>

 <!-- Footer -->
 <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
   <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2018</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
 </footer>

 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need for this. Bootstrap stable already has a fade feature. Apply the class ``carousel-fade`` to ``.carousel``

Comment: isn't mentioned in the official documentation

Comment: It is, just not on the site. See the readme in the github docs: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/docs/4.0/components/carousel.md#crossfade